# How to add CSS class to SimpleMarkerSymbol in GraphicsLayer

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Is there a way to bind a CSS class `.marker` to an ArcGIS `SimpleMarkerSymbol` in a graphic layer?

I have a `SimpleMarkerSymbol` called `schoolMarker` which I am styling it using ESRI's options but I need to add more CSS styles like `.marker`

```
var schoolMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    schoolMarker.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE);
    schoolMarker.setSize(30);
    schoolMarker.setOutline(null);
    schoolMarker.setColor(new Color([255,116,0,0.25]));
```

Here is the CSS class:

```
.marker{
   stroke-linecap: round;
   stroke-linejoin: round;
   stroke-opacity: 1.0;
   fill-opacity: 1.0;
   background-color: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   stroke: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   fill: rgb(0, 89, 190);
   fill-opacity: 1;
   stroke-width: 70pt;
   stroke-opacity: 1;
   opacity: 0.12;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good guide to get you started

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_styling_svg.html

Of note:

1. set the styling property of the feature layer to false. This means you are entirely responsible for styling the features.
2. Set (or find out what it is) the dataAttributes. In the rendered html they will look like this

```html
    <path fill="none" fill-opacity="0" stroke="none" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" path="M 548,163 549,163 549,164 548,164 Z" d="M 548 163 549 163 549 164 548 164Z" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" data-unique-value="LIBRARY"></path>
```

3. determine how detailed you need to be in breaking up classes and features. This is standard css organization. Do you need to style the whole feature class? use the feature className attribute. Do you need to target all of a certain geometry type? use data-geometry-type.